# OAuth2 with multiple SAML 2.0 IdPs - where to do IdP selection?

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I'm building an OAuth2 SSO server that has multiple SAML 2.0 IdPs.

At some point in the OAuth2 flow, the user will need to select which IdP they wish to authenticate against. Ideally, this page would exist in the SSO application, so it'd be part of the OAuth2 flow.

I'm wondering if this is possible, and if so, at which part of the OAuth2 journey it would occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to SAML 2.0 profile for OAuth 2.0 ([RFC ref](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7522)).

So the flow is to trade the OAuth 2.0 token with SAML 2.0 assertion on the identity federation server. When that happens, the IdP (which is SAML Identity Provider) selection will happen.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks.